# java inputstream print to console the content

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest

```
sock = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
       out  = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
       in   = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

When i try to do printing out of content inside "in" like below

```
 BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
 int b;
 while ( ( b = bin.read() ) != -1 )
 {

     char c = (char)b;         

     System.err.print(""+(char)b); //This prints out content that is unreadable.
                                   //Isn't it supposed to print out html tag?
 }
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example. You haven't shown how you're sending Google the request. If you specify that you can handle gzipped data, for example, you'd need to decompress the output first.

Comment: (Also note that your current code is effectively assuming ISO-Latin-1.)

Comment: hi,  after i open new Socket(); i do a "get index.html"  and send it over to "out" follow by trying to get the "in" like the code above. i didnt specified handle gzipped, how to find out whether it's gzipped?

Comment: If the contents are gzipped, it will be stated in the header (which wont be). HTTP 0.9 syntax doesn't tend to work any more. You need something like "GET /index.html HTTP1.0\r\n\r\n" or better "GET /index.html HTTP1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n" (IIRC).

Answer (score 20):

If you want to print the content of a web page, you need to work with the [HTTP](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) protocol. You do not have to implement it yourself, the best way is to use existing implementations such as the java API [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Here is an example of how to do it with HttpURLConnection:

```
URL url = new URL("http","www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlc.setAllowUserInteraction( false );
urlc.setDoInput( true );
urlc.setDoOutput( false );
urlc.setUseCaches( true );
urlc.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlc.connect();
// check you have received an status code 200 to indicate OK
// get the encoding from the Content-Type header
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}

// close sockets, handle errors, etc.
```

As written above, you can save traffic by adding the Accept-Encoding header and check the 
 Content-Encoding header of the response.

Here is an HttpClient Example, taken from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html):

```
   // Create an instance of HttpClient.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the HttpClient in particular. As soon as you want to do anything beyond a simple GET, it's invaluable

Comment: HttpURLConnection doesn't handle gzipped content.  I learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 16):

Very easy to create a String from a Stream using Java 8 Stream API:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

Using IntelliJ I even can set this beeing a debug expression:
[image]

I guess in Eclipse it will work similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you what to fetch the content of a webpage, you should take a look at [apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) instead of coding this yourself, expect for learning purposes or any other really good reason.