# java get data from api (I want to print the values ​in the url )

Tags: java

I want to print the values ​​in the url but I'm new can you help me?
......................................................

```
    import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Main {  
  public static void main (String[] args) { 
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    try { 
      URL url = new URL("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/rest-get-simple");
      try {
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        
        System.out.println(inputStream);
      } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        System.out.println(ioEx);
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException malEx) {
      System.out.println(malEx);
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java inputstream print to console the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083674/java-inputstream-print-to-console-the-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

    public class UrlConnectionReader {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException,             IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    try {
         in = new URL("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/rest-get-simple").openStream();
        InputStreamReader inR = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(inR);
        String line;
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you very much so how can i read array elements in url